# python type hints for spaCy

Tags: python, spacy

I'm struggling to set type hints for anything involving spaCy types.

Trying to use the return types like "Language" and "Token" from the documentation of spaCy but they don't seem to work...I'm on python 3.8.5.

As an example say I have this:

```
import spacy

def load_lang() -> what_goes_here:
   return spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

According to the docs this "Returns Language".
I tried Language or spacy.Language with no luck.
I have similar problems when working with tokens for example doing something like this:

`return [token for token in doc if not token.is_stop]`

Again docs mention "Returns Token" as the return object but I can't type hint it.
I don't want to go down the List[str] from typing as I'm assuming it's the wrong way to go.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to import with "from spacy.language import Language" and then use the Language as the return type?

Comment: what exactly happened when you put `Language` as the type hint?

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. If I just use Language or Token, etc. I get NameError: name 'Language' is not defined. If I do the additional import as per daniboy's comment, it works. I assumed importing spacy would bring these in. Thx again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be no problem if you import `Language` class using:

`from spacy.language import Language`

and then use it as the type hint:

```
def load_lang() -> Language:
   return spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Comment: Similarly `from spacy.tokens import Token` and then use `List[Token]` as an annotation for the other function mentioned.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! I (wrongly) assumed importing spacy would bring the relevant types in. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

I found I could do typing like this (at least works in VSCode):

```py
from spacy.language import Doc

nlp = spacy.load(model)
doc: Doc = nlp(input_text)
```

It appears that it cannot read `spacy.tokens.Doc` but it can read it from `spacy.language.Doc`.